# Can a Temple of the Monkey God accept another Temple as a Sacrifice?

Tags: bloons-td-5

More specifically if I make a Temple of the Monkey God then make another Temple of the Monkey God next to it, will the sacrifice consume the previously made Temple of the Monkey God and become stronger or will I have 2 Temples?

I had a chance to do this at round 124, but died on the next round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the second tower will accept the first as a sacrifice.

It becomes stronger based on the types of towers sacrificed. In the case you've given, it will only obtain stronger sunrays, (you have not given an image or description as to what other towers are there, so I assume these are the only towers to exist) because the other Temple is an upgraded super monkey.

This will actually make the tower weaker if the first tower had any sacrifices when it was built, which I would assume it did (unless you sold all of your towers to be able to afford the first upgrade).

Comment: Actually, all that a temple sacrifice to another temple does is add blades instead of darts to the attack where they shoot out in all directions. The tech terror makes the sun rays stronger. Source : http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Monkey_God

Comment: All sacrifices make the sun rays stronger (up to $30,000).  Both the Technological Terror and a Temple would also give blades/other.  In fact, every tower that is not one of the other four types (glue, ice, bomb, magic) will give blades.  Source:  http://archive.ninjakiwi.com/Forum/showthread.php/17674-Temple-of-the-Monkey-God-The-Complete-Guide